# Can't install Bitnami MEAN stack on Windows 10

Tags: mongodb, windows-10

I am a beginner with Bitnami MEAN stack and facing problem installing Bitnami MEAN stack on windows 10. Downloaded setup from

https://bitnami.com/stack/mean

and when I try installing everything goes fine but just before finishing installation it says Bitnami stopped working in a popup and installation fails.
same setup runs fine when I try it on my windows 7 machine. can someone help please.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you run it as administrator? Try this because sometimes this kind of failure happens because it tries to write some files in a restricted area. Try this or them point your installation to your user area. This second options is good, but only effective if you are the only user requiring the installed product.

Comment: I tried but that din't work for me.

Comment: You mean the run as admin option? And the other option, of pointing your installation to your user area? Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with version  win64 3.2.7. 
I downloaded version 3.0.2 from [this link to version 3.0.2](https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/meanstack/3.0.2-0/bitnami-meanstack-3.0.2-0-windows-installer.exe)

(I also disabled antivirus Windows Defender during installation. I am not sure it made any difference)

It works like charm.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend it really worked like a charm thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation the stack only supports 32-bit version of Windows 10 - perhaps that's the issue here?